# Stop the control while SweetAlert is on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I am using [sweetalert2](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/) library for showing alert in my code.

```
ConfirmationMessage = function(msg) {
    swal({
            title: "",
            text: msg,
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Ok",
            cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: false,
            allowEscapeKey: true

        });
}
```

This is the JS function and I am using it at other place.

```
if (!ConfirmationMessage("message to show.")) {
    alert("if");           
}
else {
    alert("else");
}
```

My issue is

> I want to stop the control when the alert is on screen and want to decide on the button push if **OK** come to **If Condition** if **Cancel** come to **else condition** but control does not wait for the response in sweetalert2.

Answer (score 5):

Creating the `swal` is an [asynchronous process, meaning you cannot just return a synchronous result from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

If you look at the [docs](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/), you can see that `swal` returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you can take advantage of that and pass the success and fail callbacks:

```
ConfirmationMessage = function(msg) {
  return swal({ ... }); // <--- return the swal call which returns a promise
};

ConfirmationMessage('message to show')
  .then(function() {
    // success happened
  }, function(dismiss) {
    // fail happened
    // dismiss can be 'cancel', 'overlay', 'close', and 'timer'
    if (dismiss === 'cancel') {
      // user cancelled
    }
  });
```